# non blocking socket programming in python

Tags: python, sockets, nonblocking

I am trying to write a non-blocking socket code. So far I've tried this:

server.py

```
import socket   

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setblocking(0)
s.bind(('localhost',60003))
s.listen(1)
#print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    conn.setblocking(0)
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    conn.sendall(data)
print 'the normal execution of data should continue'
print 'but when client connects, it has to echo back to the client then again continue its execution'
```

client.py

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost',60003))
s.sendall('Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
#s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

Also I get this error: `socket.error: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable`

No matter to whatever or however many times I change the port number.

Thanks!

Comment: Should be `s.setblocking(0)`

Comment: oh sorry, that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

You have set your server to non-blocking, so `accept` returns immediately with an error. Either set the server to blocking or use `select` to wait for events on multiple sockets.